# Publish Actions and Aggregation Management

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-opengraph

We launched Facebook Timeline integration some days ago. Further to our users' feedbacks, we have a couple of questions.

- How many actions do someone has to publish on Facebook to see them grouped together in a dedicated Scoop.it box instead of Recent activity box?
- Is there a setting to showcase that box at the top of the Timeline each time a new post is published (because right now it is stuck in the middle of the Timeline at the same spot where it first appeared)?
- Is there any way to manage the aggregation display on Facebook? (not just the template to be used, but the position inside the timeline)

Thanks a lot guys.